# Cookie not set using "set_cookie" flask method

Tags: flask

I am new user of Pythonanywhere.
The following code does not set a cookie although, I thing, I am using correct the commands.
Any help appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect, url_for
from socket import gethostname


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    username = request.args.get('nickname')
    if username == None:
        username = request.cookies.get('nickname')
        if username == None:
            return "Send me your nickname please."
        else:
            return "Welcome back " + username + ".\n If you are oneother user please send your new nickname"
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('setcookie',newuid = username))



@app.route('/setcookie/<newuid>')
def setcookie(newuid):
    resp = make_response("set cookie")
    print('resp='+str(resp))
    print('hello '+newuid)
    resp.set_cookie('nickname', newuid, max_age=60*60*24*365*2)
    username = request.cookies.get('nickname')
    if username != newuid:
        return 'Not set!!!'
    return "Welcome " + newuid


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'liveconsole' not in gethostname():
        app.run()
```

Comment: Just to clarify why this has been marked as a duplicate -- you have created a response called `resp`, which has the header to set your cookie in it, but then you are returning something else.  You need to return `resp`, not a string.

Comment: Thanks @GilesThomas have correct the code and works fine.